# Is Sin7 is algebraic over Q

Tags: real-analysis

when 7 is degree and when it is radian what will be the behaviour?Is in both the cases it is algebraic over Q or not?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\theta:=7^\circ$ so $\exp(i180\theta)=-1$, implying $\exp(\pm i\theta)$ are algebraic, as is $\sin\theta=\frac{\exp(i\theta)-\exp(-i\theta)}{2i}$. Next define $\phi=7\operatorname{rad}$ so $\sin\phi$ is transcendental, because otherwise$$\sin\phi\in\Bbb A\implies\cos\phi\in\Bbb A\implies\exp i\phi\in\Bbb A$$would contradict the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).